# Import a xml file from package swing

Tags: java, xml, swing, inputstream, document

I am using this code for import `shutdownscheduler.xml` file from my package but I am getting error:

```
public static Document handler() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        String s=xmlhandler.class.getResource("shutdownscheduler.xml").toString();
        File newFile=new File(s);
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentbuilderfactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentbuilder=documentbuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document=(Document)documentbuilder.parse(newFile);
        document.getDocumentElement();
        return document;
    }



Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\Rohan Kandwal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Shutdown
Scheduler\file:\C:\Users\Rohan%20Kandwal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Shutdown%20Scheduler\build\classes\shutdown\scheduler\shutdownscheduler.xml
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

If I give a direct path of the file then the import is working correctly. But this will result in an error once 1 create a jar file of the project and run it on other system. So I want a way to import file from my package only.

the correct path for the file is `C:\Users\Rohan Kandwal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Shutdown Scheduler\src\shutdown\scheduler\shutdownscheduler.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `InputStream` instead of `File`

```
documentbuilder.parse( xmlhandler.class.getResourceAsStream("shutdownscheduler.xml"));
```

Comment: @RohanKandwal so you can accept the answer as correct with the tick

Comment: The code is working correctly but the main problem arrives when i use this code for saving a xml file. getResourceAsStream() uses path "C:\Users\Rohan Kandwal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Shutdown Scheduler\build\classes\shutdown\scheduler\shutdownscheduler.xml" but the path should be "C:\Users\Rohan Kandwal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Shutdown Scheduler\src\shutdown\scheduler\shutdownscheduler.xml"